# validating fb cookie using md5 hash

Tags: asp.net, facebook, session-cookies

I am trying to incorporate facebook login in my ASP.NET web app and came across the following article which has a code sample for the same.

http://ntotten.com/2010/04/new-facebook-connect-in-csharp/

The following is from the article.

> Next, and most importantly, the class
>   validates the cookie. This validation
>   uses MD5 hashing to compare the
>   contents of key appended to the app
>   secret to the signature that comes in
>   with the cookie. If these values match
>   we know the key is valid.we know the key is valid.

Why is Md5 hashing being used for that? Why not SHA or some other algo?

What happens if I don't validate the cookie? Can invalid cookies be sent to the server?

In the article, he throws a new security exception if cookie is invalid? What should the user do in such a case?

I have never really worked with cookies, so I am trying to get the basics right here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after some more searching and going through the code, I finally got it.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/fb_sig

Comment: Be careful about using the fb_sig authentication. That is going away very soon. If you are starting a new app it would be better to use the new OAuth 2.0 authentication system. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/canvas

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you just use the SDK I made to do the verification. http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com. That article was basically the first code I wrote when starting that SDK. The sdk will handle pretty much everything you will need to do to develop facebook app on .Net. We use it where I work on some very large facebook apps hosted on windows azure.

The SDK will handle all the hashing/validating for you. All you need to do is this:

```
var app = new FacebookApp();
var session = app.Session;
if (session != null) { 
  // Session is valid 
} else {
  // Session is not valid
}
```

The session object is validated before it is returned to you.

Comment: Nathan, I have had a look at the SDK you have developed and it is a rework for me if I switch to the SDK now. But good work, will definitely try that in the future.